# Likelihood and multinomial distribution notation trouble

Tags: probability, bayesian, likelihood, multinomial-distribution

I was asked to prove that dirichlet distribution is conjugate for multinomial distribution but I'm not sure what the notation below which I was showed really means:

$x_1,...,x_k|\theta_1,...,\theta_k \sim Multinomial(n,\theta_1,...,\theta_k)$

Does that mean each $x_1$ is a multinomial or does that do the likelihood of my given sample is multinomial? if each $x_1$ is multinomial so would all of them be random vectors? Would dirichlet conjugate prior hold for both situations?

Comment: I would definitely argue that the likelihood of your given sample is multinomial. That's much more usual notation. That is, the likelihood function is given by $$L(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k|\theta_1,\theta_2,\dots,\theta_k)=\frac{n!}{x_1!\,x_2!\cdots x_k!}\,\prod_{i=1}^k\theta_i^{x_i},$$ where $\sum p_i=1$ and $\sum x_i=n.$